# error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token

Tags: c++, class

not sure whats wrong, the error i keep getting is in the title with line 9:19
help please?

it says my post is mostly code so im trying to add enough text to make it work...

```
#ifndef PiggyBank
#define PiggyBank

class PiggyBank {
    private:
        bool isbroken;
        double savings;
    public:
        PiggyBank(){                        <-----*!*!*!*!*
            isbroken = false;
            savings = 0.0;
        }
        PiggyBank(double savings1){
            isbroken = false;
            savings = savings1;
        }
        ~PiggyBank(){
            if(isbroken) cout << "Poor Broken Pig!" << endl;
        }
        double getsavings(){
            return savings;
        }
        bool depositmoney(double deposit){
            if(deposit >= 0 && !isbroken){
                savings += deposit;
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }
        double smash(){
            double returnvalue = savings;
            isbroken = true;
            savings = 0.0;
            return returnvalue;
        }
};
#endif
```

Comment: First, format your code. You should then be able to find the problem yourself.

Comment: got it. sorry, first time asking a question

Comment: You should look into what this does: `#define PiggyBank`.

Comment: following from the previous comment, change it as `#define PiggyBank_H`

Comment: ok thanks, i will give it a try

Comment: Guys stop with the down votes the question isn't that bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your

```
#define PiggyBank
```

and change it to

```
#define PIGGYBANK_H
```

because `PiggyBank` is a class.

Comment: `PiggyBank_H` is still a bad name. It's a macro, so it should be `PIGGY_BANK_H`.